# Weird Swift 4 type system

Tags: ios, json, types, swift4, xcode9

Can someone explain the best best way to figure out Int types, since Swift 4 I have so many troubles with JSON because of this

[image]

cause this is so common situation when I trying to map same json object to core data entities and PONSOs

so,

```
id: Int = json["id"] as? Int // works
id: Int32 = json["id"] as? Int32 // doesn't work
```

as a result I'm unable to satisfy both requirements at the same time. Can I anyhow avoid this absolutely senseless int situation in Swift 4?

Comment: If you have any specific JSON problems, please show the JSON and the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: The above code doesn't demonstrate anything JSON-related. `[String: Any]` is "a dictionary of String to absolutely any data type that can be expressed in Swift." That is often sloppily used for JSON, but parsing JSON with NSJSONSerialization should never generate the dictionary you've given here. Nothing above is "senseless," it looks to be exactly following the rules, so it may be helpful to explain the problem you're trying to solve. JSON has no 32-bit or 64-bit integer types.

Comment: Note that Swift's Int matches ObjC's NSInteger, and (as in ObjC) is the recommended type for almost all "integer-like" things in Swift. Specific bit-widths are strongly discouraged unless required for low-level interactions or ensuring very large integers on a 32-bit platform. They are not designed to be general use in Swift; they're designed for when you need very precise sizes and want to be warned when you're violating size requirements.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is confusing is because `as?` has two completely orthogonal meanings in Swift, depending on the context. When dealing purely with Swift types, `as?` is a dynamic cast that returns non-`nil` only if the type is literally an instance of the type on the right-side of the `as?` operator:

```
import Foundation

let dict: [String : Any] = ["Foo" : 3 as Int]

print(dict["Foo"] as? Int)
print(dict["Foo"] as? Int32)
print(dict["Foo"] as? Int64)
```

This returns `Optional(3)` for the first log, and `nil` for the other two, because the type is an `Int` and not an `Int32` or an `Int64`.

However, when the type of the item being cast is an *Objective-C* type, then `as?` is no longer a strict dynamic cast, but instead causes *bridging* behavior:

```
import Foundation

let dict: [String : Any] = ["Foo" : 3 as NSNumber]

print(dict["Foo"] as? Int)
print(dict["Foo"] as? Int32)
print(dict["Foo"] as? Int64)
```

This returns `Optional(3)` for all three logs, because this is no longer a dynamic cast—indeed, an `NSNumber` instance is not a member of any of the three types to which we tried to cast. Instead, `as?` causes Swift to *bridge* the Objective-C type, `NSNumber`, to an appropriate Swift type if it can. Since Swift has logic to bridge `NSNumber` to `Int`, `Int32`, and `Int64` (along with a host of other numeric types), we get `Optional(3)` for all three logs. However, if you try to cast to something like `Decimal` for which there's no `NSNumber` bridging logic, you still get `nil`.

An interesting side-effect of this is that `as?` does not follow the transitive property:

```
let foo: Int = 3
print(foo as? NSNumber as? Int64) // Optional(3)
print(foo as? Int64)              // nil
```

Anyway, if you cast your values to `NSNumber` first, you should then be able to cast from there to any of the numeric types that the Objective-C bridge supports, which is probably what was going on under the hood with your old Swift 3 code. Alternatively, if you actually know the type that the value is supposed to be, you can use one of the other integer types' initializers:

```
let dict: [String : Any] = ["Foo" : 3 as Int]

let foo = (dict["Foo"] as? Int).map { Int32($0) }
```